# How to find nodes' names on linux cluster

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, mpi, cluster-computing

I am using a linux cluster with 8 processors, though I have no way of contacting to it's administrator or anyone more familiar with using it. I am trying to run an MPI program on all nodes, but I cannot create a --machinelife file without knowing their names. So my question is as follows - how can I find names of all nodes, being able only to write commands from one of them? Is it even possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What scheduling software is used on this cluster? If it is using PBS/Torque, you can read the file `$PBS_NODEFILE`. Just run `cat $PBS_NODEFILE` to see the names of all nodes that have been assigned to your job.

Comment: You could examine the network configuration of the head node and try to guess or scan the network for other nodes. Most MPI implementations will accept IP addresses instead of hostnames. Also, look in `/etc/hosts` - the names might be there. In any case, this question is off-topic here and you should really ask it on the [Super User site](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your concern, unfortunately none of it worked. cat $PBS_NODEFILE in result only disconnects me (I am using WinSCP). I do not know what scheduling software is the cluster using. Also I don't have access to /etc/hosts file. Seems like I need to use a cluster I know anything about ;]

Answer (score -1):

If you can't get the list of nodes from the batch scheduling system as described in the comments, you might be able to get around that limitation by starting up as big of an MPI job as possible and having every rank print out its hostname.

Comment: Thanks for advice! Tried that, I only got one name for around 150 processes, typing -np close to 200 returned memory error.